# Keeping current live counts of MongoId collections in rails (polling vs. Socket.io)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, sockets

Ok, so there are a million polling vs socket.io questions on here. I have implemented socket.io, but my questions is more specific. I am using ROR and MongoDB (Mongoid). I have a nav bar that has two items on it "Active" and "Queued".

I want something like this to be displayed in the navbar.

```
"Active (34)" "Queued (23)"
```

I wondering what the best way is to keep counts of these objects. I have a User object and a Thing object (active things, queued things). Would it be best practice to keep counts on the User object? So my User object I would need two new attributes (active, queued), where I increment and decriment the attribute of the User object Then use a socket.io connection to keep track of the counts to display in the navbar? Keep in mind, these counts will change quickly; 5 "things" might go from queued to active every 3 seconds.

Or would I make a socket.io connection to run a count on a users queued things and active things in the db? Seems like count on the db would a strain on the server.